# Velocity of a floating object underwater

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, acceleration, velocity

I tried to find an equation for the speed and acceleration of an object floating from a certain depth of water to the top. But the equation always gives an imaginary solution in the case of floating where the weight ($m\cdot g$) is less than the displaced water volume's weight ($V\cdot\rho\cdot g$). I would ask If somebody knows a better solution or If there is something wrong with my equation?

The following is an explanation of the steps I did:

$m=$ mass of the object

$V=$ volume of the object

$g=$ gravitational acceleration

$CD=$ drag coefficient

$\rho=$ density of water

$$F= F_b - F_g - F_d$$

$$ m\cdot a = V\cdot\rho\cdot g - m\cdot g  - \frac {\rho\cdot CD\cdot A\cdot v^2}{2} $$

$$ \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{(V\cdot\rho-m)g}{m} - \frac{\rho\cdot CD\cdot A\cdot v^2}{2\cdot m} $$

By solving this differential equation using Mathematica to get the value of the velocity (v) as follows:

```
DE= v'[t]-(((V*p-m)*g)/m)+(p*A*Cd*(v[t]^2)/(2*m));

sol=DSolve[{DE==0,v'[0]==(((V*p-m)*g)/m)},v[t],t];

v=v[t]/.sol[[1]];
```

the velocity ($v$) and acceleration ($a$) equations are:

$$ v = - \sqrt{\frac{2(m-V\cdot\rho)g}{A\cdot CD\cdot\rho}} \cdot\tan \left(\sqrt{\frac{A\cdot CD\cdot g\cdot\rho\cdot(m-V\cdot\rho)}{2}}\left(\frac{t}{m}\right)\right) $$

$$ a= \sqrt{\frac{(V\cdot\rho-m)g}{m}} - \frac{(m-V\cdot\rho)g}{m}\cdot\tan^2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{A\cdot CD\cdot g\cdot\rho\cdot(m-V\cdot\rho)}{2}}\left(\frac{t}{m}\right)\right) $$

Comment: *"But the equation always gives an imaginary solution"* I don't see any. The problem has a Real solution.

Comment: I haven't looked at your work yet, but is the starting depth such that the density of the water can be considered constant from there to the surface?

Comment: Hi OP! If you could try to tidy you question up a bit (for example, see the MathJax guide here - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ) you might find that the users on PSE have an easier time reading your question, and you'll get better and higher quality answers!

Comment: It might be useful to calculate the *terminal velocity*.

Comment: @Gert If I assumed the object to be an empty box. so that .it's weight (m*g) is less than the buoyancy force (V*water density*g). The term sqrt(m-V*p) in the velocity and acceleration equations will always give an imaginary solution.

Comment: @MC2k thanks, I edited it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceleration changes sign depending on whether the object is heavier or lighter than water, so you have to change the sign under the square root for the velocity as well (so that the argument is always positive). You may want to check out my web page https://www.physicsmyths.org.uk/buoyancy.htm for a full derivation and explanation including plots for some example cases. I quote the final result for the velocity from there

$$v(t) = v_T \cdot tanh(\frac{g\cdot (m-m_d)\cdot t}{v_T\cdot (m+m_d)})$$

with the terminal velocity

$$v_T=\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot|m-m_d|\cdot g}{\rho\cdot C_D\cdot A}}$$

where

$$m_d = \rho \cdot V$$

is the displaced mass.

Note that in contrast to the result you quoted, the argument of the $tanh$ function (you wrote actually $tan$ by mistake) has $m+m_d$ in the denominator not $m$. This is because gravity has to accelerate not only the mass $m$ but also the displaced mass $m_d$ (in the opposite direction). Otherwise a buoyant object with zero mass would have an infinite acceleration, which is not possible (the maximum acceleration a buoyant object can achieve is in fact the free fall acceleration $g$.)

I have plotted the resulting velocity as a function of time for the case of a buoyant object in the gravitational field of the earth ($g=981 cm/sec^2$ with cross section of $A=1 cm^2$, mass $m=0.5 g$, density of the medium $ρ=1 g/cm^3$ (water) that is $m_d=1 g$, and a drag coefficient $C_D=0.47$ (sphere).

[image: velocity of buoyant object]

The red curve is for the usual (incorrect) theory which neglects the mass  $m_d$ of the displaced fluid  in the denominator of the $tanh$ function above, the blue curve does correctly take the displaced fluid mass into account according. Whilst the terminal velocity $v_T$is identical in both cases, the time it takes to reach this velocity is substantially different.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR!!

Comment: I have read your web page and it is really helpful. I see from equations (8) to (10)  that the velocity equation should be derived from the case Fg>Fb then change the sign of the argument under the square root has to be changed if the object is denser than the medium (m>md).  It is like we could take the absolute value of (m-md) to get the magnitude of the velocity (v).

Comment: @Abdulsalam_Musaad Yes, that is correct. You can take the absolute value, but only under the first square root, which is the terminal velocity (this is just a scalar)

$$v_T=\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot|m-m_d|\cdot g}{\rho\cdot C_D\cdot A}}$$

not in the expression for the actual velocity

$$v(t) = v_T \cdot tanh(\frac{g\cdot (m-m_D)\cdot t}{v_T\cdot (m+m_D)})$$

Note that it is actually $tanh$ not $tan$ in the second equation and the denominator in the argument should be $m+m_D$ not $m$ (as explained on my web page  https://www.physicsmyths.org.uk/buoyancy.htm )

Comment: @Abdulsalam_Musaad  Sorry, I made a typo above. That should be $m_d$ in the second equation as well, not $m_D$

Answer (score 0):

You have set-up the differential equation correctly. (Other than restating all your logic and equations, I dont know how to give you faith that I have looked at your work and know it’s correct. With only two caveats as below, this confirms you up to the point of the mathematica. I dont extend my answer past there.)

You **do not** need to consider the variable density of the water. Water is rather incompressible and won’t vary in density beyond negligible amounts, which would not be true if this were being done in air. The only other thing I would caution about is that the drag can change with velocity; I mean the term itself can change due a changing coefficient or even changing functional form in different flow regimes (obviously the amount of drag depends on the value of velocity $v$, which is not what I’m pointing out). If this is a very shallow depth and low speeds, assuming the turbulent drag form of quadratic could significantly overstate it. Did you look at moody’s relative roughness chart or how will you find $C_D$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I am not well informed about this topic "drag". Could you please refer me to good references about the topic?  So I could do more reading.